# Связать XML-элементы с элементами расширенного XSD (Java)

Tags: java, xml, xsd

У меня есть XSD-схема, в которой у каждого `<xs:element>` (и `<xs:attrinbute>`) есть дополнительные элементы и атрибуты (не из неймспейса xs). Что-то наподобие

```
<xs:element name="elem" xl:attr1="value1">
    <xs:complexType> ... ... ... </xs:complexType>
    <xl:foo attr2="value2"/>
    <xl:bar/>
</xs:element>
```

Также у меня есть XML-документ, который мне нужно распарсить в DOM-модель, и каждому элементу/аттрибуту в этой модели сопоставить соответствующий тег из схемы и получить все включённые дополнительные xl-элементы и атрибуты.

Есть ли способ сделать это, не прибегая (или облегчив) к ручному парсингу XSD, с учётом всех типов, ref и прочего?

Причём, это должно работать для любого произвольного XSD, без перекомпиляции.

Comment: Xml-schema (xsd) нужна для валидации, а не для парсинга. Вопрос не понятен. Чтобы загрузить xml-документ в DOM-модель, схема не нужна.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Требуется именно соотнести элемент в DOM-модели XML-документа с элементом в XSD-схеме, который его описывает при валидации, и найти дополнительные теги из неймспейса xl.

То есть, если я получу тег `elem`, то мне нужен способ узнать, что в моей расширенной схеме для этого элемента `xl:attr` равен `"value1"`, и есть теги `foo` и `bar`

Comment: Есть какие-то подвижки? Мне тема интересна. Вот только в текущем виде сама схема невалидна. Дайте больше информации, покажите как саму схему побольше, так и валидируемый xml.